# Encapsulate Socket.io events within Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am looking to separate my Socket.io events/init from my main node server logic. The goal is to not only maintain the Socket.io code, but also maintain any events that I may emit.

I'm a little overwhelmed with understanding the scope of this and the method of encapsulation with Node and was hoping to get some clarification on a better way of doing things.

**server.js**

```
//-- Socket.io
var http = require('http').Server(app);

//-- Encapsulate Socket init/events
var io = require('./socket.js').listen(http)

var api = express.Router();

api.route('/users/:user_id')
    .put(function(req, res) {
        io.dispatch(req.body.event);
    }
}

//-- Start Server
http.listen(port);
console.log('Server started on port: ' + port);

io.init(app);
```

**socket.js**

```
'use strict'

var io = require('socket.io');
var ioJwt = require('socketio-jwt');

var clientsConnected = 0;
var ioServer;

exports.listen = function(http, app) {
    ioServer = io.listen(http);
    return ioServer;
}

exports.init = function(app) {

    ioServer.use(ioJwt.authorize({
        secret: app.get('secret'),
        handshake: true
    }));

        ioServer.on('connection', function(socket){
        connect();

        socket.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('Socket.IO error:');
            console.log(err);
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            disconnect();
        });
    });
}

function connect() {
    clientsConnected++;

    console.log('user connected. ' + clientsConnected + ' total.');
}

function disconnect() {
    clientsConnected--;

    console.log('user disconnected. ' + clientsConnected + ' total.');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "encapsulate" here?  What specific goals are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Move the code associated with Socket.io to a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal communication the two modules need to have is that the http server has to be provided to the sockets module so it can initialize itself properly and the http server must call the sockets module to dispatch appropriately.  So, you can pursue modularization that has only those two connections:

**server.js**

```
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var dispatch = require('./sockets.js')(http);

var api = express.Router();

api.route('/users/:user_id')
    .put(function(req, res) {
        dispatch(req.body.event);
    }
}

//-- Start Server
http.listen(port);
console.log('Server started on port: ' + port);
```

**sockets.js**

```
'use strict'

var io = require('socket.io');
var ioJwt = require('socketio-jwt');

var clientsConnected = 0;
var ioServer;

module.exports = function(server) {
    ioServer = io.listen(server);
    ioServer.use(ioJwt.authorize({
        secret: app.get('secret'),
        handshake: true
    }));

    ioServer.on('connection', function(socket){
    connect();

    socket.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('Socket.IO error:');
        console.log(err);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        disconnect();
    });

    // return dispatch function
    return function(data) {
        io.dispatch(data);
    }
}

function connect() {
    clientsConnected++;

    console.log('user connected. ' + clientsConnected + ' total.');
}

function disconnect() {
    clientsConnected--;

    console.log('user disconnected. ' + clientsConnected + ' total.');
}
```